Grabbing Dynamic Range of Different Width and Height
I want to get the ranges of various size.  Here is my data:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aa2dyaY04zzqk7BfYkFm0TEZIvd20R--FJ06L8AtIpI/edit?usp=sharing
Background
Data 1, Data 2 and Data 3 are exactly what they look like on the spreadsheet.  Between each data, they are separated by a column stack with "|" character.  Please note that Data 1, Data 2, and Data 3 are of different width and height.
Data 1, Data 2 and Data 3



Data 1



Data 2




Data 3









Date
Time
Venue
|
Date
Time
Venue
Guest
|
Date
Time
Venue
Company
Guest
|


20/8/2025
15:00
KT
|
18/7/2026
03:00
TWW
Peter
|
24/6/2021
05:00
CWB
JOS
Yan
|


20/8/2025
15:00
KT
|
18/7/2026
03:00
TWW
May
|
24/6/2021
05:00
CWB
JOS
Uri
|


20/8/2025
15:00
KT
|
1/8/2021
18:25
LCD
Luke
|
1/8/2021
18:25
LCD
HAA
Patrick
|


20/8/2025
15:00
KT
|
1/8/2021
18:25
LCD
Tom
|
1/8/2021
18:25
LCD
HAA
Ether
|


20/8/2025
15:00
KT
|
1/8/2021
18:25
LCD
Brian
|
1/8/2021
18:25
LCD
HAA
Jan
|


18/7/2026
03:00
TWW
|
20/8/2025
15:00
KT
Lam
|
20/8/2025
16:00
KT
FLX
Tom
|


18/7/2026
03:00
TWW
|
20/8/2025
15:00
KT
June
|
20/8/2025
16:00
KT
FLX
Brian
|


18/7/2026
03:00
TWW
|
20/8/2025
15:00
KT
Tam
|
20/8/2025
16:00
KT
FLX
Hyde
|


18/7/2026
03:00
TWW
|
20/8/2025
15:00
KT
Wong
|
20/8/2025
16:00
KT
FLX
Wong
|






15/4/2023
07:00
WTS
Goode

20/8/2025
16:00
KT
FLX
Pat







15/4/2023
07:00
WTS
Pei













15/4/2023
07:00
WTS
Betty













15/4/2023
10:00
TSW
Prime













15/4/2023
10:00
TSW
Sue










Anticipated Result
For each Data 1, Data 2 and Data3, I want to use a formula to grab the range as you see on my right portion spreadsheet.
Data 1



Date
Time
Venue




20/8/2025
15:00
KT


20/8/2025
15:00
KT


20/8/2025
15:00
KT


20/8/2025
15:00
KT


20/8/2025
15:00
KT


18/7/2026
03:00
TWW


18/7/2026
03:00
TWW


18/7/2026
03:00
TWW


18/7/2026
03:00
TWW



Data 2



Date
Time
Venue
Guest




18/7/2026
03:00
TWW
Peter


18/7/2026
03:00
TWW
May


1/8/2021
18:25
LCD
Luke


1/8/2021
18:25
LCD
Tom


1/8/2021
18:25
LCD
Brian


20/8/2025
15:00
KT
Lam


20/8/2025
15:00
KT
June


20/8/2025
15:00
KT
Tam


20/8/2025
15:00
KT
Wong


15/4/2023
07:00
WTS
Goode


15/4/2023
07:00
WTS
Pei


15/4/2023
07:00
WTS
Betty


15/4/2023
10:00
TSW
Prime


15/4/2023
10:00
TSW
Sue



Data 3



Date
Time
Venue
Company
Guest




24/6/2021
05:00
CWB
JOS
Yan


24/6/2021
05:00
CWB
JOS
Uri


1/8/2021
18:25
LCD
HAA
Patrick


1/8/2021
18:25
LCD
HAA
Ether


1/8/2021
18:25
LCD
HAA
Jan


20/8/2025
16:00
KT
FLX
Tom


20/8/2025
16:00
KT
FLX
Brian


20/8/2025
16:00
KT
FLX
Hyde


20/8/2025
16:00
KT
FLX
Wong



Current Try
You will see I tried to use offset function in cell S8, W8 and AB8, where the offset function variable are referenced above these cells.
Given the setting of the above, are there any ways that can identify the width and height or column?  Or, are there more clever methods to achieve the anticipated results?  Thanks.

So your idealistic scenario is to not provide Start cell, Height, Width as input parameters?

Start cell provided, height and width not provided, thanks.


You may try:
=let(Σ,indirect(T4),
  offset(Σ,,,index(match(,0/(offset(Σ,,,rows(A:A))<>""))),xmatch("|",offset(Σ,1,,,columns(1:1)))-1))



You can use:
=ARRAYFORMULA(LET(s,INDIRECT(T4),
   OFFSET(s,,,
     MATCH(,0/LEN(OFFSET(s,,,9^9))),
     XMATCH("|",OFFSET(s,,,,9^9))-1))) 

